# Spring: I want get the relative or the full path of resource in jsp or controller

Tags: spring, resources, path, relative-path

I have some user uploaded pics store in "resource/pics", I want show in jsp, but always wrong path.
I tried

```
 request.getSession().getServletContext().getResource(filepath);
```

but it return:

```
jndi:/default-host/mvc/resources/pics/bec7838a-55dc-4f8e-86c1-fb9e9067909d.jpg
```

My resource is configed in servlet-context.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

My resource dir in：/webapp/resources

so my /resources/pics/bec7838a-55dc-4f8e-86c1-fb9e9067909d.jpg is at .../webapp/resources/pics/bec7838a-55dc-4f8e-86c1-fb9e9067909d.jpg

I do not need the "jndi:/defaulf-host". I know I can use substring to made it, but I think spring Framework should supply some function to get the resource to path or URL.

I want get this resource path to user in jsp or controller

Comment: What is the location of folder "resource/pics" in your spring project?

Comment: in servlet-context I config <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Answer (score 0):

Use in your jsp page

```
<img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/pics/${pictureName}"/>
```

In your Controller you put on the model a bean with name pictureName

```
model.addAttribute("pictureName", "picture.jpg")
```